# Line having two stroke

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to draw a line with a dashed stroke in Photoshop CC. However, the result below has two stroke stacked on top of another and not aligning.[image: 2 stroke on 1 line]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I think you should check the layer in your Appearance panel. It looks like you've applied a dashed stroke twice - once to the stroke itself, and also to the layer the stroke is on.

Comment: Where can i find the Appearance panel? I think it's only available in Illustrator

Comment: Oops, sorry thought you were using Illustrator.  In Photoshop check your layers, looks like you might have duplicated a layer by accident.

Comment: I tried creating another line, but the result are the same. I changed it to path and it fixed the problem

Comment: Oh, actually I think I can see what the problem is. If I zoom in, I can see you've applied a stroke to a shape rather than just a single path. Draw a straight line with the Pen tool instead, and apply the stroke and dash to that.

Comment: Yes that is what confused me. Apparently, the line tool draws a rectangle with 1 px height. Setting the height to 0 px doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, that's because any shape in Photoshop must have a size of at least 1px, and because Photoshop is a raster image editor, something that is 0px would be invisible. A vector on the other hand is just a single path.  It might be better to do work like this in Illustrator - because then you don't need to worry about pixels at all. Photoshop is really a photo editor, it only has very basic vector support.  For example, unlike Photoshop, the Line tool in Illustrator doesn't create a shape, it creates a single path.

Comment: You'll need to use the pen tool to make a line that's simply a line segment with two end nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop's line shape tool actually creates a very thin rectangle, which results in a double stroke effect when used the way the OP has described. The solution is to simply use the pen tool to create a line.